# Attaching default params with a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In order for a user to use my search form, they type a user's name, press submit, then rails brings up that user's homepage. I am still a beginner, and the "homepage" the user arrives is a response to the `GET` method pointed at the URL `http://localhost:3000/center/show_user?utf8=%E2%9C%93&name=test&commit=Search` when I type the user name "test" in the search box.

In the controller action `center#show_user`, I have set `@user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])`
and in the view, it displays well with `<%= @user.name %>`.

I would like to make a form on the `center#show_user` page for creating a new "item". An item is defined at belonging to the user in the scheme and a user is defined as owning many items (a user has an item_id column and an item has a user_id column).

When this form is submitted, how do I include with it the current user_id, inherited from the params in the url on the page hosting the form? For example, if I go to the page of the user named "sample_user", I want to be able to submit a "new item" form and have the user_id automatically included along with that form.

---

'Central' controller code for this page is

```
def show_user
    @user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "user_id", current_user.id %>
```

to form.

Comment: ok, thank you. This was my initial inclination but I wasn't sure it'd be secure. Would this be vulnerable to somebody changing the value of this field?

Comment: also I don't have a current_user defined

Comment: right, one can change the value of that field. Rather you should access the user id by whatever way you do in controller.

Comment: that's what i am trying to figure out how to do. I updated the question to include my controller code.

Comment: It depends on what you are using for authentication like in devise (gem commonly used for authentication with rails app) one can get current user by current_user helper(method).

Answer (score 0):

You should create the "item" through the relation with the user. That means:

Given this in your user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

Do the following in the controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])
  @user.items.create(params[:item])
  # redirect_to or something different...
end
```

This will automatically build the relation for you (basically filling in the `user_id` field for you). The reason for doing it this way is that users can't mess with your form and fill in other user ids in the hidden field.

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method 'items' for nil:NilClass` in regards to `def create_item
    @user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])
    @user.items.create(params[:item])
   redirect_to 'root'
    
  end`

Comment: It can't find a user. This might be because you don't have the `name` parameter available. Passing a user's name in every request raises some red flags, because usually you don't want people to be able to change other users. Passing it along in the parameters without authentication is not safe.

Comment: But if you still want to do it, make sure you add the name parameter to the url you are posting to. So something like this: `<%= form_for @item, url: item_path(name: @user.name) do |f| %>`